# Problema al modificar nombre de migración en laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-8

Cree un modelo en Laravel 8 que se llama "Direccion" pero me creó una migración con el nombre de "direccions" el cuál lo cambié por "direcciones" tanto en el nombre de la clase, como la tabla de la base de datos y en el nombre de la migración, pero al intentar hacer una consulta en la tabla me la sigue buscando por "direccions" y quiero saber donde puedo cambiar eso, les muestro mi código:

```php
class CreateDireccionesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('direcciones', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('id_cliente');
            $table->string('alias');
            $table->string('calle');
            $table->integer('numero');
            $table->integer('apto')->nullable();

            $table->foreign('id_cliente')
                    ->references('id')->on('clientes')
                    ->onDelete('cascade'); //Si se elimina un Cliente también se elimina la dirección

            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('direcciones');
    }
}
```

Y el error que me sale:

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'karre.direccions' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `direccions` where `direccions`.`id_cliente` = 1 and `direccions`.`id_cliente` is not null) (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\karre\resources\views\admin\clientes.blade.php)

Comment: Como laravel usa plural pero en ingles debes modificar el nombre de tu tabla en el modelo agregando la propiedad table asi= protected $table = 'direcciones';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

si no me equivoco en tu modelo debes añadir lo siguiente:

```
protected $table = "direcciones";
```

Limpia cache despues de hacer este cambio y debería de tirar contra el nombre bueno

Comment: Perfecto, lo solucioné con esto, me di cuenta que al no poner eso, laravel "autogenera" el nombre de la tabla en la consulta poniendo el nombre del modelo en plural en inglés. Muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

Honestamente Laravel suele ser un poco delicado con esas cosas te recomiendo que cuando corrijas todo el archivo copia el contenido en otro lugar, borre el archivo de la migración y vuelve a ejecutar el comando para crearla `php artisan make:migration direcciones`, pega el contenido ahi y listo. Eso debería funcionar...